# How to make child div fill parent div keeping the parent padding in CSS?

Tags: css, height

Wanted to know about the trick that would enable a child div to follow the height of parent div "Responsively".
height: 100% covers the padding too. How can I make child fill the "available" space?

Comment: I think you need to Flexbox, please look for this article: https://www.w3docs.com/snippets/html/how-to-make-a-div-fill-the-height-of-the-remaining-space.html

Answer (score 0):

Set the `box-sizing` of the parent to `content-box`

> **content-box**
>
> This is the initial and default value as specified by the CSS standard. The width and height properties include the content, but does not include the padding, border, or margin.

```css
.parent {
  height: 80vmin;
  margin: 5vmin;
  background: lightblue;
  padding: 5vmin;
  box-sizing: content-box;
}

.child {
  background: rebeccapurple;
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div class="child"></div>
</div>
```